# Single page application with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I'm trying to build a single page web application using Spring MVC, relying on native Spring MVC controllers (with model and views) and common rest controllers that return JSON information.

I want to briefly explain you what i'm doing with a simple example:

1. if the user click on the home page button inside the menu, an Ajax
   method is called and it sends a GET HTTP request to my server that
   handles the request with a Spring MVC controller, returning the
   rendered html file of the home page, coming from a JSP file
   containing JSTL and Spring tags.
2. Once the Ajax method receives the content of the homepage it changes
   the content of the main div inside my html body with this new one.
   In the end what the user has, is the homepage without refreshing the
   page (sorry for the game of words).

The only problem is that if a user writes inside the browser the url of the GET HTTP request that the Ajax method uses to get the homepage content, right now what happens is that he will load the homepage content inside the browser(and of course i don't want him to be able to send this get http request manually).

I really hope to have explained myself with this example and I would like to ask you if you have any suggestions to give me in this direction in order to solve this problem! I know that using a framework such as React or Angular, things would be much much easier but i still have to learn one! This will be the first upgrade I'll do in the future to this webapp.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Try to authenticate all your HTTP call from JavaScript to your API (for example with a token like JSON Web Token). If the token is not present or incorrect, return a 401 HTTP Status(Unauthorized).

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this really sounds like something that could help me! Do you have a guide to suggest?

Comment: I answered just below. You have to search by yourself to do so, but I added a good link ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use @RestController and not @Controller(or your could do @Controller for the class and @ResponseBody for the single method).Therefore your return method should be a ResponseEntity. According with the flow of your code, you can set the HttpStatus.OK or HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment! Yes actually I'm doing exaclty what you say! Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly, the problem is that if the user types the url inside the browser and press enter, he gets the same content on the screen, and this is something I don't want!

Answer (score 1):

Try to authenticate all your HTTP call from JavaScript to your API (for example with a token like JSON Web Token). If the token is not present or incorrect, return a 401 HTTP Status(Unauthorized).

There is a lot of good tutorial like this one: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

You just have to add an Http Header to your ajax call with the token returned by the authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna try this solution ASAP!